# Java - Flink -> Fastest way to filter List of Tuples

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have stream that is coming from Kafka, and I'm manipulating with Flink. Part of the stream is composed by one Integer that I'm monitoring which indicate the height. I would like to save "height" and "counter" into a list ot Tuple2<Integer, Integer> where the first f0 is the height and the second element f1 is the number of times the same height has been previosly seen into the stream.

input: 170 -> ListofTuples[170,2]

input: 170 -> ListofTuples[170,2]

input: 120 -> ListofTuples[170,2] [120,1]

input: 140 -> ListofTuples[170,2], [120,1], [140,1]

input: 140 -> ListofTuples[170,2], [120,1], [140,2]

input: 140 -> ListofTuples[170,2], [120,1], [140,3]

input: 170 -> ListofTuples[170,3], [120,1], [140,3]

And so on.

What can be the fastest way to check the ListOfTuple to update the counter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keyBy(height field), and have a stateful `MapFunction` that updates a `ValueState` with the count of how many times the key has been seen.

Though you didn't say what you wanted as a result of the stream - I'm guessing maybe emit the `<height, count>` tuple each time it gets updated, which would be easy to output from your `MapFunction`.

See the [word count example](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html) for an example similar to this, where it's counting word occurrences vs. integer value occurrences.

Comment: Hi, the stream is already KeyBy and this process is inside a Stateful RichMapFunction. The main stream have many more information and when I'm mapping it is for a process in particular where I'm just working with height. Can i KeyBy by a variable insie a MapFunction of a stream that is already been KeyBy another variable? To explain me better: If the Main stream have a KeyBy for "school Name" can i also KeyBy Height of people in that school? Thanks

Comment: About the output instead, yes you are correct i would like to have an <height, count> that is updated every time a new record in the stream is received.

Comment: Hi @SimAzz please edit the question to include the detail about the stream already being keyed, and then I can edit my answer to address it, thanks!